# MySQL Query to multiply and round off existing values

Tags: mysql

Sorry for being to vague last time I asked this question.

I have this existing table in my database the shows the prizes for certain events. I am looking to run a query in phpMyAdmin to correctly make the existing prizes be multiplied by 50, divided by 2 then rounded up to the nearest whole number.

For example rank 1 in event_id 1 would be (120*50)/2 shown as new_prize.

an example of my table is as follows:

```
event_id   ranking     prize
1          1           120
1          2           60
2          1           10
2          2           5
```

I hope I have better explained it this time. Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: How is that different from multiplying by 25?  Neither requires any rounding unless the original value is not an integer.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to have prizes increased to the power of 2, I was reading an example of it earlier which confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can use `ROUND(X)` , `CEILING(X)` , `FLOOR(X)` for getting round off value

For Example

1.ROUND(X)

```
 select *,round((prize*50)/2) as new_price from events
```

It will return `5` for values of `4.8`, and `4` for '4.1'

2.CEILING(X)

```
select *,ceiling((prize*50)/2) as new_price from events
```

It will return `5` for `4.8`

3.FLOOR(X)

```
select *,floor((prize*50)/2) as new_price from events
```

It will return `4` for `4.8`

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

`select *,round((prize*50)/2) as new_price from events`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple

```
SELECT round((prize*50)/2) as New_prize FROM table where event_id = 1
```

And remove WHERE condition to get all records

Answer (score 0):

```
update events set prize = ceil(prize * 50 / 2)
```